# Graph with edges between nodes and edges

Tags: graph-theory

I was wondering if there is a name for this type of graph (does it even belong to the class of graphs ?) :

A graph that allows edges between a node and an edge. So if we call our nodes A, B and C then we have something like Edge(A,B) and Edge(C, Edge(A,B)).

[image: .]

**Graph description :** three nodes A, B and C. Edge(A,B) Edge(C, Edge(A,B))

I've looked around but I can't find a name for this type of graph, I only known it's not:

- hypergraph (i'm not interested in edges between multiple nodes)
- multigraph (several edges between the same pair of nodes)

I'd be greatful for your help !

Comment: Edges are thought of as strictly connecting vertices.  Can you get the same effect by adding edges and/or vertices rather than making edges that connect to other edges?  For example, with vertices A, B, and C.  Why not have three edges: each connecting one of the pairs of vertices?

Comment: I don't think it would be the same, replacing Edge(C, Edge(A,B)) with Edge(C,A) and Edge(C,B) would change the nature of the relations. I want C to be linked to only 1 object (the edge between A and B), whereas in your case, C would be in 2 different relations. But maybe this is a hint that what I'm looking for doesn't satisfy the requirements of graphs.

Comment: It sounds like this new approach minimizes the degree of vertices, but it's changing a pretty fundamental understanding about edges and vertices.  Is there a particular problem you're hoping to investigate with this structure or are you just playing around with graphs?

Comment: I certainly haven't encountered it before, but if you were wanting to have, say a streetmap between cities, you could add vertices for the street intersections.  In your example, adding the vertex $X$ at the intersection point between the two former edges, removing the original edge and replacing with edges adjacent to $X$., giving you the vertex set $\{A,B,C,X\}$ and the edge set $\{\{A,X\},\{B,X\},\{C,X\}\}$.  You would just remember the vertices representing cities are considered "special" compared to the vertices merely representing uninteresting intersections of streets.

Comment: It might be easiest to represent this with a second graph, whose vertices are the edges of the original graph.

Comment: What would having a name for this type of graph gain you? If you're trying to see if someone has already looked at a problem about such graphs, why not ask about that problem directly?

Comment: (1) It's mostly curiosity, I was surprised not to find a name for this type of structure + wanted to find out what sort of problems were involved in the manipulation of such structures (there is also some links to some linguistics / computational linguistics problems concerning the description of some syntactic structures). I don't have a specific problem in mind, instead I'm trying to find what problems have been descrived by people cleverer than me :).

Comment: (2) @saulspatz I don't really understand how this works, I would have two vertices: 1 (formerly the edge between A and B) and 2 (formely the edge between C and Edge(A,B)), but what would be the new edges ?

Comment: Not sure may help, but I was also looking through the way how to model this real life situation as a graph : A and B likes each other, C is jealous and does not like their friendship, C likes A and likes B too, but does not like that relationship, so  Likes(C,Likes(A,B)) is not the same as Likes(C,A) + Likes(C,B) . and maybe we will need more generalized data structure to model this type of situations